# Re-initializing THREE.WebGLRenderer for toggling anti-aliasing

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I want a simple solution. A toggle button which refreshes a Three.js scene depending on the user, if he wants an anti-aliased version of the scene or not. My `refresh_scene` function is as follows:

```
function refresh_scene()
{
    scene.remove( floor );
    floor.geometry.dispose();
    floor.material.dispose();
    floor = null;
    scene.dispose();
    scene = null;
    controls.dispose();
    controls = null;
    camera = null;
    renderer.dispose();
    renderer = null;
    canvas = null;
    cancelAnimationFrame(reqAnimFrame);
    visualizer();
}
```

This function is called every time the button is pressed. The `visualizer()` then just displays all objects again. This also includes getting the canvas, making a new renderer, new scene, etc. For some reason, the new renderer does not display an anti-aliased version of the scene, but the same scene over and over again, despite the fact that the toggle button toggles an `antialiasing_` value which is then used in the `visualizer()` function to reinitialize the renderer according to the new value:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, antialias: antialiasing_});
```

where `antialiasing_` is a bool which toggles `true` or `false`. Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Can upload other parts of code if necessary.

Comment: The [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) provides an option in the `PROJECT` tab to enable/disable antialiasing. It works without issues. So there seems to be a problem in your application. Unfortunately, it's not clear from what you have shared so far what's going wrong. Consider to demonstrate the issue with a simple editable live example.

Comment: Ensure your device supports antialias (could be turned off at the driver level or be a blacklisted item in the browser (for chrome check chrome://gpu/ )) The spec says that *"If the value is true and the implementation supports antialiasing..."*  I assume that `true` means truthy, but best to use `true` rather than `truthy`. Three only forces `false` if antialias is `undefined` and keeps truthy and falsy values as is when getting the context. see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js

Comment: I dug in the code real quick and you can [see](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/7c3d2f44fd34796b038b74190d64cf4fbd3574cf/editor/js/Sidebar.Project.Renderer.js#L27) that the antialias setting being changed requires recreating the renderer.